# Error creating geography element using "STGeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(..." - SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial, computational-geometry

I am getting the following error when trying to create geography elements in sql 2008:

> NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine
>   or aggregate "geography":  System.ArgumentException: 24200: The
>   specified input does not represent a valid geography instance.
>   System.ArgumentException:

Some example queries are:

```
select geography::STGeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(
53.4707 -2.24758,53.4708 -2.25079,53.4733 -2.2597,53.4743 -2.24812,53.4747 -2.24119,53.4756 -2.26244,53.4765 -2.24278,53.4805 -2.28457,53.4909 -2.37892,53.5272 -2.36252,53.7159 -2.56899,53.7165 -2.56208,53.7183 -2.62195,53.7212 -2.55478,53.7439 -2.48239,53.7443 -2.48351,53.7446 -2.48767,53.7455 -2.48894,53.7464 -2.48376,51.5126 -0.22443,51.5126 -0.22455,51.5129 -0.22522,51.5148 -0.22595,51.515 -0.22565,51.5152 -0.22007,51.5153 -0.21982,51.5153 -0.22207,51.516 -0.21593,51.5207 -0.16548,51.5274 -0.13044,51.5287 -0.1195,51.5294 -0.11581,51.5314 -0.114,51.5319 -0.10629,51.546 -0.10225,51.5468 -0.09851,51.5615 -0.09948,51.5618 -0.09859,51.5619 -0.09874,51.5621 -0.09774,51.5622 -0.09793,51.5629 -0.074843,51.5635 -0.07319,51.5638 -0.07423,51.5655 -0.07308,51.5065 -0.23453,51.5098 -0.2346,51.5125 -0.22443,51.5126 -0.22455,51.5141 -0.30077,51.3824 0.219232,51.3832 0.22189,51.3871 0.19381,51.3924 0.19631,51.4505 0.2384,51.4561 0.24682,51.4905 0.26753,51.6112 -0.13568,51.614 -0.1423,51.6149 -0.1279,51.6159 -0.0959,51.6166 -0.08625,51.6827 -0.04306,51.6827 -0.0485,50.8295 -0.135709,50.8336 -0.1389,51.0842 -0.20043,51.2584 -0.12584,51.4889 -0.49628,51.4928 -0.41087,51.493 -0.41909,51.5134 -0.40288,51.5158 -0.40192,51.5169 -0.41292,51.517 -0.41706,51.5171 -0.41794,51.5175 -0.41693,51.5189 -0.41131,51.506 -3.5765,51.5071 -3.57572,51.508 -3.57682,51.5089 -3.57687,51.5094 -3.57552,51.5268 -3.57319,51.5319 -3.57145,51.533 -3.567,51.5537 -2.54326,52.2083 -2.15995,52.2133 -2.15969,52.3653 -2.23896,52.3797 -2.25068,52.3856 -2.24433,52.3856 -2.24637,51.3017 0.14978,51.3168 -0.55901,51.317 -0.55852,51.3179 -0.5572,51.318 -0.55734,51.3714 -0.5076,51.3876 0.50573,51.3881 0.50679,51.3884 0.50491,51.3885 0.505716,51.3951 0.49271,51.3957 0.49308,51.3984 0.45032,51.3998 0.43212,51.423 0.2361,51.4259 0.23944,51.4269 0.24394,51.3017 0.14978,51.3168 -0.55901,51.317 -0.55852,51.3179 -0.5572,51.318 -0.55734,51.3714 -0.5076,51.3876 0.50573,51.3881 0.50679,51.3884 0.50491,51.3885 0.505716,51.3951 0.49271,51.3957 0.49308,51.3984 0.45032,51.3998 0.43212,51.423 0.2361,51.4259 0.23944,51.4269 0.24394,52.2027 0.13072,52.2027 0.13139,52.2041 0.12733,52.2048 0.12558,52.2052 0.124187,52.2083 0.13738,52.2139 0.1106,52.2139 0.1237,52.2146 0.12279,52.2163 0.13467,52.2332 0.07004,52.2374 0.06243,52.3776 -0.25321,52.5366 -0.3223,53.3912 -1.06914,53.5818 -1.21172,53.6173 -1.23025,53.809 -1.34127,54.1533 -1.43958,54.4485 -1.66852,54.7766 -1.57715,54.7777 -1.57547,54.7777 -1.57631,54.7906 -1.53038,54.7934 -1.52982
)' , 4326)
```

or

```
select geography::STGeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(
53.4707 -2.24758,53.4708 -2.25079,53.4733 -2.2597,53.4743 -2.24812,53.4747 -2.24119,53.4756 -2.26244,53.4765 -2.24278,53.4805 -2.28457,53.4909 -2.37892,53.5272 -2.36252,53.7159 -2.56899,53.7165 -2.56208,53.7183 -2.62195,53.7212 -2.55478,53.7439 -2.48239,53.7443 -2.48351,53.7446 -2.48767,53.7455 -2.48894,53.7464 -2.48376,51.5126 -0.22443,51.5126 -0.22455,51.5129 -0.22522,51.5148 -0.22595,51.515 -0.22565,51.5152 -0.22007,51.5153 -0.21982,51.5153 -0.22207,51.516 -0.21593,51.5207 -0.16548,51.5274 -0.13044,51.5287 -0.1195,51.5294 -0.11581,51.5314 -0.114,51.5319 -0.10629,51.546 -0.10225,51.5468 -0.09851,51.5615 -0.09948,51.5618 -0.09859,51.5619 -0.09874,51.5621 -0.09774,51.5622 -0.09793,51.5629 -0.074843,51.5635 -0.07319,51.5638 -0.07423,51.5655 -0.07308,51.5065 -0.23453,51.5098 -0.2346,51.5125 -0.22443,51.5126 -0.22455,51.5141 -0.30077,51.3824 0.219232,51.3832 0.22189,51.3871 0.19381,51.3924 0.19631,51.4505 0.2384,51.4561 0.24682,51.4905 0.26753,51.6112 -0.13568,51.614 -0.1423,51.6149 -0.1279,51.6159 -0.0959,51.6166 -0.08625,51.6827 -0.04306,51.6827 -0.0485,50.8295 -0.135709,50.8336 -0.1389,51.0842 -0.20043,51.2584 -0.12584,51.4889 -0.49628,51.4928 -0.41087,51.493 -0.41909,51.5134 -0.40288,51.5158 -0.40192,51.5169 -0.41292,51.517 -0.41706,51.5171 -0.41794,51.5175 -0.41693,51.5189 -0.41131,51.506 -3.5765,51.5071 -3.57572,51.508 -3.57682,51.5089 -3.57687,51.5094 -3.57552,51.5268 -3.57319,51.5319 -3.57145,51.533 -3.567,51.5537 -2.54326,52.2083 -2.15995,52.2133 -2.15969,52.3653 -2.23896,52.3797 -2.25068,52.3856 -2.24433,52.3856 -2.24637,51.3017 0.14978,51.3168 -0.55901,51.317 -0.55852,51.3179 -0.5572,51.318 -0.55734,51.3714 -0.5076,51.3876 0.50573,51.3881 0.50679,51.3884 0.50491,51.3885 0.505716,51.3951 0.49271,51.3957 0.49308,51.3984 0.45032,51.3998 0.43212,51.423 0.2361,51.4259 0.23944,51.4269 0.24394,51.3017 0.14978,51.3168 -0.55901,51.317 -0.55852,51.3179 -0.5572,51.318 -0.55734,51.3714 -0.5076,51.3876 0.50573,51.3881 0.50679,51.3884 0.50491,51.3885 0.505716,51.3951 0.49271,51.3957 0.49308,51.3984 0.45032,51.3998 0.43212,51.423 0.2361,51.4259 0.23944,51.4269 0.24394,52.2027 0.13072,52.2027 0.13139,52.2041 0.12733,52.2048 0.12558,52.2052 0.124187,52.2083 0.13738,52.2139 0.1106,52.2139 0.1237,52.2146 0.12279,52.2163 0.13467,52.2332 0.07004,52.2374 0.06243,52.3776 -0.25321,52.5366 -0.3223,53.3912 -1.06914,53.5818 -1.21172,53.6173 -1.23025,53.809 -1.34127,54.1533 -1.43958,54.4485 -1.66852,54.7766 -1.57715,54.7777 -1.57547,54.7777 -1.57631,54.7906 -1.53038,54.7934 -1.52982,53.3615 -2.2943,53.3616 -2.29438,53.3619 -2.29431,53.3626 -2.29606,53.363 -2.29748,53.3683 -2.31356,53.3687 -2.31296,53.3967 -2.26766,53.3984 -2.22994,53.481 -2.05105,53.4821 -2.05214,53.4821 -2.11473,53.4827 -2.10573,53.4828 -2.05008,53.4858 -2.05878,53.7633 -2.70157,53.7636 -2.70038,53.7672 -2.70313,53.7952 -2.98557,53.8002 -2.72228,53.8011 -2.71739,53.804 -3.02696,53.8139 -3.05028,53.815 -3.04473,53.8163 -3.05226,53.4707 -2.24758,53.4708 -2.25079,53.4733 -2.2597,53.4743 -2.24812,53.4747 -2.24119,53.4756 -2.26244,53.4765 -2.24278,53.4805 -2.28457,53.4909 -2.37892,53.5272 -2.36252,53.7364 -2.64886,53.7952 -2.98557,53.804 -3.02696,53.806 -2.70331,53.8139 -3.05028,53.815 -3.04473,53.8163 -3.05226,51.401 -0.5297,51.4052 -0.34152,51.4111 -0.300524,51.4126 -0.30176,51.4164 -0.42419,51.4191 -0.41833,51.7152 -0.3928,52.8399 -1.29605,52.8429 -1.29658,52.9216 -1.16451,52.9265 -1.16722,52.9488 -1.1511,52.9489 -1.15012,52.9493 -1.14992,52.9504 -1.14983,52.9509 -1.15128,52.9513 -1.1503,52.9514 -1.15141,52.9517 -1.15273,52.9521 -1.15199,51.502 -0.15932,51.5024 -0.1555,51.5033 -0.14984,51.5033 -0.15075,51.5042 -0.1511,51.5132 -0.16003,51.5134 -0.15871,51.5227 -0.17393,51.5685 -0.2291,51.5712 -0.23129,51.5719 -0.22982,51.573 -0.228,51.5731 -0.22961,51.5763 -0.23571,52.3953 -1.17295,52.6728 -2.07963,53.4061 -2.8963,53.407 -2.90128,53.4075 -2.90136,53.4078 -2.97954,53.4078 -2.9802,53.4078 -2.98228,53.408 -2.98106,53.41 -2.97854,53.4103 -2.90155,53.4103 -2.97767,53.4112 -2.97723,53.4133 -2.96398,53.4143 -2.96216,53.4237 -2.57435,53.4273 -2.91804,51.5033 -0.149834,51.5042 -0.1511,51.5044 -0.14749,51.5051 -0.15035,51.5051 -0.15089,51.5052 -0.15032,51.5056 -0.14872,51.5126 -0.15886,51.5132 -0.1607,51.5179 -0.16725,51.5226 -0.17378,51.5685 -0.22934,51.5686 -0.22953,51.5709 -0.23185,51.5719 -0.23053,52.4003 -1.17515,52.4768 -1.68081,52.6655 -2.06869,53.4062 -2.95647,53.4064 -2.89868,53.4064 -2.95565,53.407 -2.95622,53.4072 -2.95609,53.4075 -2.97961,53.4076 -2.98199,53.4076 -2.98408,53.4084 -2.97404,53.4087 -2.97886,53.4087 -2.98279,53.4092 -2.97452,53.4098 -2.91679,53.4213 -2.54907,51.4871 0.2647,51.4878 0.26815,51.4901 0.26826,51.4931 0.26921,51.4986 0.26975,51.4988 0.25643,51.499 0.25929,51.5001 0.25941,51.5002 0.25852,51.5019 0.26817,51.6053 0.26623,51.6087 0.26389,51.6108 0.26624,51.8917 0.8989,51.8918 0.89627,51.8918 0.89984,51.8919 0.89838,51.892 0.900363,51.8924 0.89627,51.8926 0.86479,51.8926 0.89413,51.8926 0.89605,51.8953 0.8574,51.8966 0.89092,51.5042 -0.08496,51.5051 -0.0844,51.5061 -0.08801,51.5063 -0.08826,51.5108 -0.08656,51.5114 -0.07264,51.5115 -0.07297,51.5119 -0.06908,51.5138 -0.07593,51.5152 -0.07174,51.5161 -0.08162,51.5266 -0.02797,51.5288 -0.01608,51.53 -0.01417,51.5311 -0.01715,51.5927 0.21329,51.5929 0.20981,51.8917 0.8989,51.8918 0.89627,51.8918 0.89984,51.8919 0.89838,51.892 0.900363,51.8924 0.89627,51.8926 0.86479,51.8926 0.89413,51.8926 0.89605,51.8953 0.8574,51.8966 0.89092
)' , 4326)
```

I have many similar queries than run just fine.

Can anyone tell me why these particular ones fail? I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see this from your data, but it seems that you are running into this problem: [The LineString instance cannot overlap itself over an interval.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895372.aspx)

It might be useful for you to use the [MakeValid() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933835.aspx) to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the line overlapping itself.

I managed to create a valid geography object  using 
http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/

Great article here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2009/06/05/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-2.aspx